# How to use YouTube Data API v3 to retrieve video url links?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My product is a media player box without a browser supports. Our YouTube application on the box used to use v2 to retrieve videos's url links with mp4 formats to make a playback:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID?format=3
```

Recently, all video links using this method direct me to a warning video, saying that I need to migrate to v3.

I study the v3 but cannot find a way to retrieve the video links. 
How can I supposed to play YouTube videos without a browser on my box?
Are there any official ways?

Comment: V3 of the YouTube API does not expose the MP4 link for any of the videos except for those owned by a currently logged in user.

Comment: Are there any solutions for non-browser devices?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.